# How to make procedural broken glass material with a particular shape

Tags: cycles-render-engine, node-editor, procedural, glass

[image]

Hello,
I want to create something like this image does, in cycles. Does anyone know how to make procedural broken glass that can look like this ? I am looking for a way to not have the random voronoi cracks.

Thanks!

Comment: Hello :). What have you tried so far and where *exactly* are you stuck?

Comment: hello @JachymMichal ! i've tried with the voronoi texture as mentionned in other posts, and managed to have a basic cracked glass. But i am looking for a way to "control" the shape of the cracks, like in the reference picture, the cracks are kind of unusual.

Comment: Hello :). It might be waaay easier to simply paint a b&w texture with the particular shape.

Comment: thank you @JachymMichal :)) could you expand a bit on how to do that?  thanks!

Comment: Hey :). I'd do it in photoshop/illustrator, I don't paint textures in Blender :).

Comment: ok thanks a lot @JachymMichal ! but then what would the node set-up look like :) ?

Comment: Well, just plug the texture into the Transmission socket of Principled BSDF and perhaps also use it as a bump map :).